# doing groupby on time and other column to get unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below:-
[image]

I am doing a group by on status_event to get the unique country code:-

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min'))['country_code2'].unique()
```

[image]

But I want to do a group by on every 15 minute time and getting a unique code for every status_event.

Something like below but with time:-

```
df.groupby('status_event')['country_code2'].unique()
```

[image]

expected df :-

```
2021-01-01 17:00:00 10028 [AE,US,SA,US]
2021-01-01 17:00:00 5043  [AE,US,SA,US]
2021-01-01 17:00:00 5046  [AE,US,SA,US]
2021-01-01 17:15:00 10028 [US,SA,US]
2021-01-01 17:15:00 5046  [AE,US,US]
```

Comment: It seems you already answer your question. If not , can you check and add more details.

Comment: No, I haven't My expected df is time status and then unique country code.

Comment: Isn't that the second image you have here?

Comment: No, please have a look now, in the second image the time is missing, That's not the 15-minute aggregate.

Comment: check my answer. I check and it works on a sample df

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I did a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
df.groupby(['status_event', pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')])['country_code2'].unique()
```

you need to make your time the index df.set_index('time')